# How to change frequency that Outlook 2007 checks for exchange mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

I would like to reduce the frequency that Outlook 2007 checks for new emails against my exchange account. I have tried to change the Send/Receive Groups, but that does not seem to be working as I have it set to send/receive every 30 minutes and it receives almost instantaneously. I even made sure that the group is set to "Include the selected account in this group".

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is not possible, at least via [this response](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/change-the-frequency-of-checking-mail/2126bf6c-11fd-4fb1-95cc-45fbda662849?msgId=ccbdd397-a51f-44cc-8698-314c6d46726d)

> Exchange accounts will check mail once per minute. This schedule cannot be changed.

Comment: Does anyone know if this answer has changed with Outlook 2010 or 2013?